# Xcode Thread 1: Program recived signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4

i know there are many post about this problem, but any of those can help me.

Well, I have Mac OS X Lion and Xcode 4, when I create only one text field and try to write something in the simulator I get the error "Thread 1 Program recived signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

I also tried "NSZombieEnabled=YES", but still the same problem, and I've seen, the problem does not happen in Xcode 3.

[screenshot here](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/668/excbadaccess.jpg)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Does this also happen on the device? I've had the same problem once and somehow, it helped to disable autocorrection in the simulator's keyboard settings. Seems to be a bug and it never happened on an actual device.